# Replace multiple string in a single shot

Tags: sql

I am writing a stored procedure 
 to replace a string which belongs to a column of table  with some values .  string data is like this -

****dear #employee we are happy to raise your #CTC L  by #increment from #date****

we will pass #employee , #CTC     and #date through parameter.

output should be  - Dear Ram we are happy to raise your ctc 3.5 L by 10% from 22-013-2014

I dont want to loop through is there any way to do it in a single shot

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chain calls to replace:

```
replace(replace(replace(msg, '#employee', emp), '#increment', inc), '#date', fromDate))) -- etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE (
    REPLACE ( 
        REPLACE (
            REPLACE ( "*dear #employee we are happy to raise your #CTC L by #increment from #date*" , "#employee", "Ram")
        , "#CTL", "ctl 3.5" ), 
            #increment,  "10%"),
            "#date", "22-013-2014")
```

Would this do?

Comment: Thank you . Well i want to make this query more generic suppose  the above string dear #employee we are happy to raise your #CTC L by #increment from #date  "   can n numbers of #variable  and those #variables are same from some tble say bookMarks hv #Name, #CTC, #Desig, #Date ....so on from our stored procedure we will always pass value for all #variables so how i will loop through these variables to replace the string ... kindly suggest

Comment: Your questions is contradictory. You first state that you don't want to loop through and now you are asking to loop through. You can't loop and not loop at the same time.

Comment: I mean to say when i change the query to new requirement  then is it possible to replace in a single shot